# Unexpected syntax error while using 'blit' on pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.4

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)
cyan = (0,255,255)
purple = (255,0,255)

bg = black

fps = 30
dispWidth = 800
dispHeight = 600
pixMove = 10

UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

def runGame():
    imgx = 3
    imgy = 3
    direction = RIGHT

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == (K_LEFT or K_a):
                    direction = LEFT
                elif event.key == (K_RIGHT or K_d):
                    direction = RIGHT
                elif event.key == (K_DOWN or K_s):
                    direction = DOWN
                elif event.key == (K_UP or K_w):
                    direction = UP

            if direction == UP:
                imgy -= pixMove
            elif direction == DOWN:
                imgy += pixMove
            elif direction == LEFT:
                imgx -=pixMove
            elif direction == RIGHT:
                imgx += pixMove

            setDisplay.fill(bg)
            img = pygame.image.load('kirby.png')
            img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (20,20)
            setDisplay.blit(img,(imgx,imgy))
            pygame.display.update()

while True:
    global fpsTime
    global setDisplay

    fpsTime = pygame.time.Clock()
    setDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((dispWidth,dispHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('kirby\'s controlled adventure')
    runGame()
```

Ok, soo when I run this code I get a syntax error on the "setDisplay.blit(img, (imgx,imgy))" (more specifically after the setDisplay.

I have no idea what the heck is wrong in this code, could anyone help me?

(I'm using python 3.4 btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the preceding line:

```
img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (20,20)
#                           ^     ^     ^?
```

Comment: OMG, thanks (I feel soo dumb now...)